# Populate dojo ItemFileReadStore from Grails "render as JSON"

Tags: javascript, json, grails, dojo

I have created a method in my controller that will give me a JSON "file" if I browse to that URL directly. It is only in memory, not on disk, as it is generated at the time you hit the URL. I am trying to use this as my data store for a dojo tree, however, when I am using this, the Tree never populates, it just sits there with the "waiting" cursor. Is there a different way to populate the data for the Tree?

Here is the code below. "getFilterTree" returns a rendered JSON object in grails

```
       var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
           url: "/SkillsDB/search/getFilterTree"
       });

       var treeModel = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({
           store: store,
           query: {
               "type":"cat"
           },
           rootId: "root",
           rootLabel: "Filter Categories",
           childrenAttrs: ["children"]
       });

       new dijit.Tree({
           model: treeModel
       },
       "treeOne");
```

Comment: What does the JSON look like?  Are you getting any errors?  Check the console output in Firebug (or whatever your browser supplies).  If it's not something obvious (like the wrong URL), most likely you just are generating the wrong model.  Dojo ItemFile*Stores need to have a very specific structure.

Comment: Can you show the code that generates the JSON and the JSON you expect it to generate for given inputs. As it stands, this question hasn't really got anything to do with grails

Answer (score 0):

It should definetely work.

For ItemFileReadStore, your json should comply with the structures shown in this page : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html